# Laravel option only for the admin (permission)

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I write a method, that which checks whether the user is an administrator in file UserController.php:

```
public function create(){
    $chackIsAdmin = Auth::user()->permissions;
    if ($chackIsAdmin === 1) {
        return view('users.adduser');
    } else {
        return redirect('warehouse');
    }
```

In table "users" I have column "permissions". Each user is assigned a number 1 or 0. 1 - is admin, 0 is NOT an admin.

I wrote also instruction if, which displays option "Add user" only the user administrator:

```
@if (Auth::user()->permissions === 1)  
    <li><a href="{{ url('user/create') }}">Add new user</a></li>
@endif
```

**It all works correctly, but I wonder whether in Laravel I can do it in a different way ??**
**Whether my way is safe?**

Comment: Overkill for this type of situation, but the Laravel solution is Authorization: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better way is to write the function on the `User` model.

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->attributes['permissions'] == 1;
    }
}
```

Then it's very easy to use...

```
return Auth::user()->isAdmin() ? view('users.adduser') : redirect('warehouse');
```